# Are compression fitting threads all the same?

Tags: plumbing, fitting

I found a weird fitting that I need but it's made by Swagelok (https://www.swagelok.com/en/catalog/Product/Detail?part=SS-400-1-6).  One side of this fitting is a compression fitting and I'm hoping to connect a standard stainless steel braided hose to it, like the ones used for connecting ice makers or sinks.  I'm just wondering if anyone might know whether normal braided hoses made for standard compression fittings would be compatible with these fittings.  The reason I ask is because Swagelok used different ferrules than the normal compression fittings I've seen.  The ferrules don't need to be compatible but the threads do if I want to connect the two together.

Comment: http://www.brasscraft.com/pdf/0302_Brass_Fittings_Catalog.pdf has a listing of ordinary brass components. I think the usual way to get the same as the Swagelok is using two fittings 1/4" tube x 1/4" MIP and 1/4" FIP  x 3/8" MIP.  To do an adaptation on an outside faucets I got some brass fittings including 1/2" FIP  x  3/4" MIP and even with pipe dope it seeped. This was outside so I just left it and hoped it would seal with time, but inside it is more critical to get no seep. I don't know if this is my poor technique or fittings which are not to standard. I have had seeps seal in time.

Comment: That fitting configuration is not "weird", it is common. You can find a brass 1/4" comp. x 3/8" MIP at any decent plumbing store,without the need for adapters. You do not say why you want the Swagelok style, they are "industrial" grade and very expensive. The thread will be the same.

Comment: @Jimmy-Fix-it some of these flexible hoses were designed to replace a female-flare nut and seal on the male flare end. Are the threads on flare the same as the threads on compression? Specifically are the threads the same pitch and whatever else is necessary for the same flexible hose to fit both M-flare and M-compression?

Comment: From the Brass Craft catalog pg 5 the thread pitch of flare and compression are different, e.g., for 1/4" flare is 20 per inch and compression is 24 per inch.

Comment: As mentioned by Jim Stewart, flare and compression fittings are completely incompatible. Not only are the threads different, but they seal an entirely different way. You would need to adapt your female flare-ended flex line with 2 adapters, an adapter that had male flare to pipe thread, then an adapter to screw into that that had pipe thread to comp. thread. I have never seen a "flare to comp." adapter.

Comment: Maybe post a picture of the end of your flex line (and/or the specification label), and the fitting you are trying to attach to.